# Monotouch - select multiple photos

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to do this in MonoTouch?

http://definelabs.com/blogs/?p=17

I don't understand much of that Objective-C code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an article on this: [Accessing iPhone Album](http://software.tavlikos.com/2011/02/13/assetslibrary/)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but there is a demo app that I've created that lets you do the features Nicklas Savonen requested.

What this demo app does is, it will get the list of images from AssetLibrary and will load them in a UItableview, then maintain a selection status, the Tick image is just an overlay image that will be hidden/visible based on selection.

The following link explains the basic steps you need to take, since it would be difficult to understand by the project:

http://helpalittle.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/monotouch-multiple-image-picker/

And you can find the complete solution at the following path: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=697F540B0A2F1506%21107

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know am not helping much at this point, but you need to learn at least a bit of ObjectiveC to be able to read it. The issues is, that all the samples and plenty of resources for iOS development is in ObjC and converting it to Monotouch is not that complex, in fact all the constructs there have C# equivalent (the blocks in the sample you posted, are in fact anonymous methods).

More to the point, multiselection of the images is done in the iOS SDK 4.x, if I find some spare time this would be a nice little exercise for my blog.

As to what APIs to check for this, these are asset library APIs:
ALAssetsLibrary & ALAsset & ALAssetsGroup

in Monotouch there are classes in (pseudo code):

```
using MonoTouch.AssetsLibrary;

MonoTouch.AssetsLibrary.ALAsset;
MonoTouch.AssetsLibrary.ALAssetsLibrary;
MonoTouch.AssetsLibrary.ALAssetsGroup;
```